# Lessons to learn from Chess.com

Tags: software, online-chess, computer-chess, websites, chess.com

How much do you know Chess.com website? Chess.com is the most successful website for chess players to use in their chess life. I'm a web developer and I'm going to create a social network for chess players all around the world. What are some strengths/shortcomings of Chess.com which one might learn from in building another site? What do you need that Chess.com or other currently chess sites do not have? Not interested in getting in a debate here, but just to discuss possible functional features/capabilities, and I understand that different users will have different priorities.

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion based

Comment: Not sure question should look like this. Maybe ok. Chess.com is pretty far from social network. I would ask the same question without mentioning chess.com at all. I know you don't mean it badly, but I think chess.com doesn't deserve to be pattern for shortcomings.

Comment: chess.com has looser moderation, but in return enjoys more flexibility in content: discussion, playing, learning materials. Personally I am interested in a site that offers customized playing bots for individualized training, from tactical puzzles to full games.

Answer (score 2):

Short comings are best illustrated by comparison.  I'd simply encourage you to compare/contrast chess.com with lichess.org.

I could observe some pluses and minus here, and that might be subjective, but it's better you discovered chess.com's defects through comparison yourself.

I'd also add - I like chess.com greatly, but I like lichess.org more.  I also play directly on the site and by app.

(some might find this response **NOT** specific enough but identifying 'shortcomings' is a bit subjective with out something to compare to)

Answer (score 2):

This question can be quite opinionated, but seeing as you are seeking to improve on the site with your own design, rather than bash it, I'll try to be objective and help out. Here are some (non-exhaustive), factual examples:

1) Users have to pay for certain features. It can be taken as a given that users would much rather prefer features for free than having to pay for them. For example, for deep analysis, playing multiple games, getting rid of ads, and more, users have to pay on chess.com

2) The majority of people on chess.com do not play variants

3) It is quite difficult for players to play against those ranked well above them, even in tournament settings

4) Mods (in select cases) have been known to abuse their privileges and ban/kick people without reason

5) The site is not open-source

Hope this helps! Would also encourage you to look at lichess, and decide what improvements you can find there.